# Componentwise addition of elements of linkedlist of same size in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I need to define a class for linkedlist in which I need to support the componentwise addition of elements of linkedlist of same size using a sign +.
I defined an operator in class that do 0 based indexing of elements in my list. Here's the definition of indexing operator.

```
 int operator[](int index)
{
 node* current = head;
 
    int count = 0;
    while (current != NULL) {
    
        if (count == index)
           
             return (current->val);
        count++;
        current = current->next;}
        
    return -1;
 
}
```

Then I tried to use this indexing to get the sum.

```
List operator+(List l)
{List res;
for(int i=0;i<length();i++)// length() gives length of List, I have already defined it in my code//
{res[i] = (don't know what to put) + l[i];

return res;
}
```

I have no idea if whatever I am trying to do is right or not. Also I don't know how to put the value of element at index i of my primary list.

please suggest a way to do so.

EDIT 1: I did indexing because it is also a part of my assignment, since I needed to do indexing already, that's why I thought of using it in my addition operator.

Comment: `(*this)[i]` but overall, this is a really bad algorithm as it scans the list over and over again

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. Let's consider two lists: {1, 5, 8} and {2, 3, 6}. You want to get a new list {3, 8, 14}, am I right?

Comment: Also you pass a copy of the list for no real reason. Furthermore I assume your list is empty initially, there's not even an element you could find; you wouldn't be able to assign a value to an rvalue anyways... Furthermore `-1` seems like a weird default. 0 would make more sense, if you're trying to add lists of differing sizes.

Comment: @MykhailoMushynskyi Yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `res[i] = (don't know what to put) + l[i];`

You can dereference the `this` pointer to call your `operator[]` on the object that the `operator+` is being called on, eg:

```cpp
res[i] = (*this)[i] + l[i];
```

Or, you can just call the operator directly like any other class method, eg:

```cpp
res[i] = this->operator[](i) + l[i];
```

However, even if this were to compile, it won't work correctly at runtime, because `res` has fewer elements than `this` and `l` have, and because your `operator[]` does not accept assignments anyway since it returns an `int` by value instead of by reference.

Implementing an `operator[]` for a linked list is generally a bad idea, but even more so when it is used inside a loop.  You end up re-iterating the list over and over and over, which is very inefficient.

There is no need for an `operator[]` in this situation.  Just use normal linked-list iteration instead (as you are doing inside of your `operator[]`), appending the new values to `res as you go along, eg:

```cpp
List operator+(const List &l) const
{
    if (length() != l.length())
        throw std::runtime_error("lists must be the same length");

    List res;
    node* current = head;
    node* l_current = l.head;
 
    while (current != NULL && l_current != NULL)
    {
        res.add(current->val + l_current->val); // or whatever your method is called...
        current = current->next;
        l_current = l_current->next;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`res[i] = (*this)[i] + l[i];` will work.

But you are trying to undo the linked part of linked lists and bumped the complexity of their addition from O(N) to O(N<sup>2</sup>). If this is an assignment, the solution will most likely not be accepted, or at least it should not be.

Just walk both lists the same way you do in `operator[]` and create the third one on the fly.

Comment: `res[i] = (*this)[i] + l[i];` won't work since `res` has fewer elements than `this` and `l` do, and because `res[i]` does not accept assignment anyway since it returns an `int` by value instead of by reference.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good catch, you have the better answer.